# Chapter or Season?

Tags: word-usage, meaning, word-choice, difference

When speaking of tv series, is there any difference between "season" and "chapter"?

- Game of Thrones, Chapter 2
- Game of Thrones, Season 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Books are organised into chapters. Multiple books may form a *series*, or be considered an ongoing *saga*.

Television series are split into *episodes*. Multiple episodes normally make up a 'season' (or in British English, a 'series'). A season or series is normally characterised by a run of episodes that were made in a production block.

However, some television series choose to use the term like 'chapter' either in place of 'episode', or to group episodes together. This may be because they have been adapted from books and the creators want to retain that structure, or perhaps it is just a stylistic choice to give it a more epic, book-like feel.